# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Items.SetColumns(String Columns) Issue

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

We have an Outlook add-in that's been in the field for a while now and seems to be stable. However, we're seeing this strange behavior on one of our non-US client's machine.

Here is the code:

```
items.SetColumns(
    "[CreationTime], [Subject], [Start], [End], [Importance], [LastModificationTime], [IsRecurring], [BusyStatus], [MeetingStatus], [ResponseStatus], [Sensitivity], [Duration]");
```

And here is the exception I'm seeing:

```
2021-01-27 09:23:28.9349|ERROR|OutlookAddin.LogProvider|System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): The property "CreationTime], [Subject], [Start], [End], [Importance], [LastModificationTime], [IsRecurring], [BusyStatus], [MeetingStatus], [R..." is unknown.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Items.SetColumns(String Columns)
```

What's interesting is the property is interpreted as one long string instead of a comma delimited one. It does seem to recognize the opening bracket since it's not included in the error, but after that treats it as one long property value.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Could it be related to Outlook being installed in a non `en-us` language code?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `"["` and `"]"`.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.setcolumns

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. We tried that and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the list delimiter on that machine is "," (open Region in Control Panel).
If it is not, use the appropriate locale specific separator when you build the list.

[image]